# Cakephp URL masking?

Tags: cakephp, url-masking

For example: I have a controller: "Services" and an action called "web". Thus, my url would be:

```
http://www.domain.com/services/web/
```

How do I mask the url, such that if I type:

```
http://www.domain.com/servicesweb
```

will display exactly as `http://www.domain.com/services/web/`

I am reading the htaccess, not sure if its a correct solution to this.

Comment: Have you read the manual chapter about [routes](http://book.cakephp.org/view/945/Routes-Configuration)?

Comment: @Juhana: Sorry, I didnt read about that. The first thing that comes to my mind was url masking(mod_alias) when the client ask me to change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you missed the [entire chapter in the CakePHP docs about Routing](http://book.cakephp.org/view/945/Routes-Configuration), which is this 'url masking' you speak of.

In your /app/config/routes.php file you will need to add this line:

```
Router::connect('/servicesweb',  array('controller' => 'services', 'action' => 'web'));
```

Be sure to read the book for clarification on routing.

Comment: Best answer. Sorry, I am new to cakephp, didnt know cakephp routing could do all this. I though I might need to use, URL masking, aliases etc